# When was copy and paste added to windows?

Tags: history

When was control C and control V added to windows?

I understand the basic history but I’m looking for the date added to windows.

Comment: I don't think this is on topic here, but it should be for Retrocomputing (see this question about the [earliest clipboard](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/19889/462)).

Comment: Copy and paste is far older than windows so it was probably always a part

Comment: A bounty? This isn't a UX question

Comment: Note: "Copy and paste" (title question) is not identical to "control C and control V" (body question), you should clarify which one you want to know. Early versions of Windows used other keyboard shortcuts for copy, paste, and cut. Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, and Ctrl+X were added later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, it was **November 20, 1985**. And I mean technically, because it was there from the beginning when Windows was introduced. Remember, Windows inherited most of the capabilities of MS-DOS, except that it uses a graphical user interface.

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but it's a good question to introduce one of the legends of UX (and specifically Human Computer Interaction): [**Larry Tesler**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Tesler). He invented [copy and paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste) while working at XEROX PARC, as well as the concepts of *user friendly*, *browser*, and *WYSYWYG* among many other inventions and developments.

The above concepts were used by Microsoft and Apple for their products (he even led Apple's development team), so **copy and paste** was included by default in both operating systems (as well as in all other existing OS), which answers your question.

## However...

The first **copy and paste commands** belonged not to OS, but to text editors, and they date from the early 1960s. What Tesler invented was the "OS -wide" functionality (copy text across applications)